# Как сделать выбор по динамическому id?

Tags: jquery, html

Такой вопрос. Есть инпуты:

```
<input type='submit' id='pd_1' value='$id' >
<input type='submit' id='pd_2' value='$id' >
<input type='submit' id='pd_3' value='$id' >
и т.д.
```

на php выглядит так:

```
<input type='submit' id='pd_$ids' value='$id' >
```

Вопрос как сделать выбор по динамическому id в jquery ?

Comment: а зачем id динамический в принципе ? Если нужен то выбрать то можно, но это криво, лучше добавьте им класс и выбирайте по нему.

Comment: именно нужен динамический

Comment: тогда класс добавьте. [выборка по атрибуту](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) тоже существует, но она медленная. [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541898/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-id-with-jquery-using-regex)

Comment: Нельзя так. Нужно чтобы при клике на поле submit возвращалось его значение value.

 function send() {
   var id = $('# Что тут поставить ?').val();
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            data: {id:id},
            success: function (html) {
   $("#result").append(html);
    }
        }); 
}

Comment: `$(this).val()`

Comment: получаю вот такую ошибку 
Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: у вас нет toLowerCase() в вашем коде. в общем вот два способа отловить то что вам нужно - [первый](http://jsfiddle.net/85khB/2/), если у вас событие submit, [второй](http://jsfiddle.net/85khB/) если событие click